# How to conditionally output data based on JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Any help?
Let's say i have this array of objects.

```
const data = {
post: [
  {
  id: 1,
  name: "lorem A",
  lastseen: 1,
  },
  {
  id: 2,
  name: "lorem B",
  lastseen: 16,
  },
  {
  id: 3,
  name: "lorem C",
  lastseen: 3,
  },
  {
  id: 4,
  name: "lorem D",
  lastseen: 10,
  },
]`}
```

I'm working with simple react time component to display "hr" or "hrs".
How to check if "data.lastseen" value is greater than 1?
So i can display like this "1 hr" or "2 hrs"

I know to map this but conditionally add and display "hr" or "hrs" to each object I'm having trouble with.

```
const mapData = data.map((seen) => seen.lastseen)
```

I googled it to extract values from Object we can use "Object.values()"
But not sure how to combine with map.

**Updated code**
This is my react component

```
<Main>
{Request.data.post.map((user) => {
    return (
      <Col
      //I'm display other component here 
        <User user={user} />
      //I'm display other component here 
       </Col>
    );
})}
```

```
 const User = ({ user }) => {
  return (
    <Col>
      <Seen user={user} />
    </Col>
  );
};


const Seen = ({ user }) => {
  return <React.Fragment> {user.map((seen) =>
        seen.lastseen == 1 ? seen.lastseen + "hr" : seen.lastseen + "hrs"
      )}</React.Fragment>;
};
```

Comment: what issue  are you facing right now

Comment: I got this error "TypeError: user.map is not a function"

Comment: `user` is not an array so you are getting this error

Comment: But it's from const data array objects right? I had been scratching my head for 3 days now.

Comment: update to this it will work in your case `<React.Fragment> { Object.keys(user).map((key) => (key == 'lastseen' ? (user[key] == 1 ? user[key]+'hr': user[key]+'hrs') : null)) } </React.Fragment>`

Answer (score 4):

Since you can't use if else in jsx use ternary operators like this instead:

```
const mapData = data.map(seen => (seen.lastseen == 1 ? 'hr': 'hrs'));
```

Comment: Thank you, i think this will do. But i got error "data.map is not a function"  when  I added this code to my file. I think because I added inside map function also. Is it?

Comment: If data is defined above mapData this should work. Because you are rendering an array.

Comment: Hello, I'm updating my code and applied the code you suggested.  What's wrong with my code implementation? Still i got error "TypeError: user.map is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i].lastseen === 1) {
        // display 1 + 'hr'
    } else if(data[i].lastseen > 1) {
        //diplay data[i].lastseen + 'hrs'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution:

```js
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const data = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "lorem A",
        lastseen: 1
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "lorem B",
        lastseen: 16
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "lorem C",
        lastseen: 3
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "lorem D",
        lastseen: 10
      }
    ];
    return (
      <div>
        {data.map(item => {
          return item.lastseen === 1 ? (
            <p key={item.id}>{item.lastseen}hr</p>
          ) : (
            <p key={item.id}>{item.lastseen}hrs</p>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, i figured it out thanks for help.

I updated my seen component to

```
const seen = ({ user }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {user.lastseen == 1 ? user.lastseen + "hr" : user.lastseen + "hrs"}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

My mistake I thought "user" is still an array which is not it's an object.
That's why I keep getting an error "TypeError: user.map is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

From your code above

```
const Seen = ({ user }) => {
  return <React.Fragment> {user.map((seen) =>
        seen.lastseen == 1 ? seen.lastseen + "hr" : seen.lastseen + "hrs"
      )}</React.Fragment>;
};
```

will thrown an error

> TypeError: user.map is not a function

As `user` is an object you can use `Object.keys` and map over it. So change your code

```
const Seen = ({ user }) => {
     return <React.Fragment> { Object.keys(user).map((key) => (key == 'lastseen' ? (user[key] == 1 ? user[key] + ' hr': user[key] +' hrs') : null)) } </React.Fragment>;
 };
```

and it will work fine.